# Parse, AsyncStorage and React Native

Tags: react-native, parse-platform, expo, parse-server, asyncstorage

Trying to work out using Parse with React Native and using Back4App as my BaaS.
Running into a problem when setting up my asyncstorage (from react native).

```
Parse.setAsyncStorage(AsyncStorage);

//Paste below the Back4App Application ID AND the JavaScript KEY
Parse.initialize('myappid', 'sdk');

//Point to Back4App Parse API address
Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/';
```

This is the initialization code I am trying to run.
Unfortunatly, I am running into this error:

```
App.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: 
parse_react_native__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default.a.setAsyncStorage is not a function
```

Trying different versions of parse, different imports, different storages, nothing works. Here are my imports:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import Parse from 'parse/react-native';
```

Additional information:
I have another project working but it is running expo 40 and parse 2.19 with asyncstorage 1.17.9.
this project is running expo 46 and parse 3.4.3 with asyncstorage 1.17.10.

I want to use expo 46 for its additional features. I tried downgrading to the same versions of parse and asyncstorage but without any success.

Comment: Have you tried the steps in [this guide](https://www.back4app.com/docs/react-native/parse-sdk/react-native-sdk) related to the expo installation?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it helps to rebuild the project in Xcode after `pod install` -- which you had to run in this case, right?

Answer (score -1):

**Instead of** import Parse from 'parse/react-native';

**use**
import Parse from 'parse/react-native.js';

**just adding .js**